# ASP application domain change now shows intermittent IIS default page

Tags: asp.net, iis

There is a ASP application hosted on IIS which had its domain changed via the bindings tool. Now, it intermittently shows the IIS default page but fully works if we access it via the old domain.
What might be causing it to intermittently work on the IIS server?

Comment: Stop the default web site on IIS, and you would be served by a much better error page.

Comment: Did you mean to say "intermittently" when you typed "interminably" the first time?

Comment: I did (updated original post). I removed the default document and it just 404s.